# How to specify a local custom SSL truststore for Hornetq client when connecting via JNDI naming server

Tags: ssl, jms, hornetq

We have a java client (mule app) which is using hornetq client (v2.3.25.SP20)  for connecting to the HornetQ remote server via the JNDI naming server (port 1099).
The connection is secured with SSL. The driver is requiring the javax.net.ssl.trustStore property to be set explicitly. Otherwise, it does not find the trust store.

We would like to specify a custom truststore for the session.
But setting  a global property javax.net.ssl.trustStore may affect other applications. So, we are looking for the alternative.

I've coded a custom trust manager (X509TrustManager) which points to the custom truststore. But the issue is that it's used only for establishing connectivity with the JNDI server. Then, the actual connection object is taking the trust store location from the remote server (in case, of course, if javax.net.ssl.trustStore is not set).
The error HQ212007 is produced:

> connector.create or connectorFactory.createConnector should never
>   throw an exception, implementation is badly behaved, but we will deal
>   with it anyway.
>
> Unable to create NettyConnector for myserver:4447
>   Failed to find a store at *remote server keystore location*

Googling the error code, I've found very similar issue described with not solution provided [here](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/2135081).

So, is there another way of specifying a path to a truststore for hornetq client when connectivng via JNDI, so, that it would not affect other applications running on the same VM system? Or, may be there is a way to disable the SSL certificate validation on the client side completely - this would work for us as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are HornetQ-specific system properties to set SSL configuration parameters. Check out [the documentation for HornetQ 2.4.0](http://docs.jboss.org/hornetq/2.4.0.Final/docs/user-manual/html/configuring-transports.html#d0e3620).

These properties were added after 2.3.0.Final but backported to the 2.3.x branch which is why they're available in 2.3.25.SP20 but aren't documented in the 2.3.0.Final docs.

In short, you can use these system properties instead of the global ones:

- `org.hornetq.ssl.keyStore`
- `org.hornetq.ssl.keyStorePassword`
- `org.hornetq.ssl.trustStore`
- `org.hornetq.ssl.trustStorePassword`